# Why can you add $-a$ to both sides of $a+b=a+c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

```
 We are given that a+b = a+c


   (-a) + (a+b) = (-a) + (a+c) 

   ((-a)+a) + b = ((-a)+a) + c           by BR2

   (a+(-a)) + b = (a+(-a)) + c           by BR1

            0+b = 0+c                    by BR4

      b = c                      by BR1 and BR3
```

How is (-a) added? Where does that come from? How is that step allowed/legal?

Comment: https://math.usask.ca/emr/proofs/sym_proof1.html

Comment: Ummm.... you can add the same value to both sides of an equality and the equality is preserved.  Weren't you aware of this?

Comment: Is it weird to say you should do your own work? If you and I have the same amount of money and we both spend $\$a$, will we still have the same amount of money?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  I'm afraid that might be a weird answer, which is not allowed.

Comment: What are $a,b,c$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork why can't we just cut a's on both sides? How do we know what's allowed, what's not allowed?

Comment: @IonAag Would you be equally bothered if +a was added to both sides?

Comment: @IonAag but that is precisely *how* you cut $a$s from both sides.

Comment: stack is nice and I would be bothered, but I see point in Randalls statement, Ill need time to explore this

Comment: You can cut them—it’s called cancellation. That’s what people really do to speed up the process; no one mentally adds $-a$ and then combines all the $a$ terms then reduces them to $0$ then adds $0$.

Comment: Please don't downvote.  This is a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the “Axioms” or common notions written in Euclid's *Elements.*  The [complete list](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/cn.html) is:

> 1. Things which equal the same thing also equal one another.
> 2. If equals are added to equals, then the wholes are equal.
> 3. If equals are subtracted from equals, then the remainders are equal.
> 4. Things which coincide with one another equal one another.
> 5. The whole is greater than the part.

Your derivation uses Axiom 3.  Now that we understand subtraction as just another form of addition (by negative numbers), Axioms 2 and 3 are considered equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a certain quantity by a name $a,$ and another person knows the exact same quantity, but by the name $b,$ then we usually say that $a$ is equal to $b,$ or write $a=b,$ for short. Thus, adding any amount $q$ to that quantity (or subtracting from it) may be written by you as $a+q$ and by your antipodal friend as $b+q.$ Both of you still have the same quantity after the transformation, so we may still write $a+q=b+q.$ For short, we say that $a=b$ implies $a+q=b+q.$

This fact is quite general, as you can easily see by using any other operation instead of addition of $q.$ Whatever you do to $a$ is done similarly to $b,$ since they're just one and the same thing, just under different names. Thus, we say that to preserve an equality $a=b,$ any operation $t$  that changes $a$ to $t(a)$ also changes $b$ to $t(b),$ and moreover, we must have that $$t(a)=t(b).$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ are numbers, $a+b$ is a number and $a+c$ is a number. Since we are given that $a+b=a+c,$ we now know that $a+b$ and $a+c$ are the **same** number.

Let’s call that number $x.$ So now $x=a+b$ and $x=a+c.$

Since $a$ is a number, so is $-a,$ and since $x$ is a number, so is $(-a)+(x).$
Moreover, a number is equal to itself, so

$$ (-a)+(x) = (-a)+(x).$$

Now all you need to do is substitute $a+b$ for $x$ on the left and substitute $a+c$ for $x$ on the right, provided you accept that one thing can be substituted for an equal thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the first axiom of solving equation, you can add to RHS and LHS the same quantity and the result of the equation doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=y$, then $z+x=z+y$ because sum is a function.

Comment: I agree with the result but I don't get your explanation. What does sum being a function have to do with the property?

Comment: @DonThousand: Plugging in the same input will always give you the same output. So if $f(t) = z+t$, then $x=y$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ahh I see. That's an interesting way to reason this.

Comment: @DonThousand Epistemologically, functions are things that send equal things to equal things. Which is why $a+b=a+c$ implies $(-a)+(a+b)=(-a)+(a+c)$.